# Is doctoral fellowship to be considered as funding source for a journal article?

Tags: publications, paper-submission

As title suggests. First year Doctoral fellow with a scholarship. The article has no bearing on my Doctoral thesis. It is a side project. My synopsis hasn't even been finalized yet. So should I have mentioned and declared ny fellowship as a funding source while submitting the paper?

Comment: To clarify more, the scholarship is given by my country's government's university regulator called UGC. I am also in my first year and the article has nothing to do with my intended thesis when it comes to overlap. It is not a grant or project specific scholarship. It is merely a merit scholarship

Answer (score 3):

There is no *need* to list it if the funding didn't support the research (if any) that went in to the paper.

But it might be at least courteous to mention that you are "personally" supported by as scholarship, naming the source.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where the conventions of the journal probably override any answer that we can provide. In general, I don’t see people acknowledging fellowships that were provided “for study” — for example fellowships that all graduate students in a department receive. Similarly fellowships that were awarded “for excellence” to attract a particular candidate to a university are often not acknowledged. On the other hand, fellowships that are “for research” or designed to further your research goals (even broadly) typically get acknowledged (in my field).

Regardless, it is okay to let this “grey area” slide for now and then ask the editor if you get a revision.

Comment: In my experience, this is wrong.  Also, if it's a doctoral fellowship it is for research.  A doctorate is a research degree.

Comment: Well, then everyone in my PhD granting department is wrong because none of us ever acknowledged the uni funding, just above and beyond funding we had to apply for…

Comment: For instance, I would acknowledge NSF funding but not generic Harvard funding that came as part of admittance. I would acknowledge an above and beyond research funding that was administered by a committee or center at Harvard.

Comment: I would say that, same as with salaries, fellowships that all students receive are generally acknowledged by stating the affiliation. If I see "university of X" next to someones name, then I will generally assume that that university supported that person. Similarly, the university of X will certainly feel their contributions acknowledged by that.

Answer (score -1):

If you were paid by a fellowship, or your tuition was paid by a fellowship, while you worked on a paper, then *yes* the fellowship *must* be acknowledged in the paper.

You can skip the acknowledgement only if you did not use any fellowship resources in any way.  If you do not include the acknowledgement, you take on a small risk of angering the funder and violating the journal's policies.

Comment: Too stark. If I study, say, physics and publish an article "Personal Energy in Taiji", do I need to list my fellowship?

Comment: This depends a lot if the fellowship is being provided by the university or a third party. In the former case, your affiliation is sufficient acknowledgment of your funding. In the latter the funding should acknowledged if in anyway this funding helped you in preparing this work.

Comment: To clarify more, the scholarship is given by my country's government's university regulator called UGC. I am also in my first year and the article has nothing to do with my intended thesis when it comes to overlap. It is not a grant or project specific scholarship. It is merely a merit scholarship. I have given my affiliation to an Uni controlled by the authority that lends the scholarship too.